# Remove element when Datetime.Month starts a new month? MVC5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have this scenario and I'm not sure if this is possible, that's why I am asking it here:

I have a calendar and in that calendar there are events. An event has all sort of properties. Like day,month etc. (Here is the class: pastebin.com/zPzWMSE0)

```
public class Agenda
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string StartTimeEvent { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Would it be possible that if a new month starts, the events gets automatically deleted when its not in the new month anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: deleted from what? you've only shown the class, not the storage mechanism

Comment: Deleted from a partial view.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the events that their month is smaller than current month:

```
int Month = DateTime.Now.Month;
Events = Events.RemoveRange(Events.Where(e => e.Month < Month));
```

If you want to also include the day (as you said in the comment):

```
int Month = DateTime.Now.Month, Day = DateTime.Now.Day;
Events = Events.RemoveRange(Events.Where(e => e.Month < Month || (e.Month == Month && e.Day < Day));
```

Comment: Thanks will defenitely try that. And what if I want them deleted the day after they were held? Maybe that would be better I geuss.

Comment: @RoyKooiman you are welcome. I edited my answer to include your comment